# How extract values from this list (from rgbif) and convert it in data frame in R?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply

I have this list `l`

```
l

    $`5216014`
    $`5216014`[[1]]
                name     key    rank
    1       Animalia       1 kingdom
    2       Chordata      44  phylum
    3 Elasmobranchii     121   class
    4     Rajiformes     884   order
    5        Rajidae    5877  family
    6           Raja 2342057   genus
    7  Raja montagui 5216014 species


    $`5216208`
    $`5216208`[[1]]
                   name     key    rank
    1          Animalia       1 kingdom
    2          Chordata      44  phylum
    3    Elasmobranchii     121   class
    4        Rajiformes     884   order
    5           Rajidae    5877  family
    6         Amblyraja 2420436   genus
    7 Amblyraja radiata 2420446 species
```

I would like to extract only `row` number 7 for column `name` and `key` and to create a database like this:

```
df

name                key
Raja montagui       5216014
Amblyraja radiata   2420446
```

I tried with `lapply` function:

```
lapply(l,function(x) x[7])
```

but the result is this:

```
$`5216014`
$`5216014`[[1]]
NULL


$`5216208`
$`5216208`[[1]]
NULL
```

I tried to transform `l` in a data frame:

```
data.frame(matrix(unlist(l)))
```

but I obtained one big column with all data as:

```
kingdom
phylum
class
order
family
genus
species
Animalia
Chordata
Elasmobranchii
4943
Rajiformes
Rajidae
Raja
Raja montagui
1
44
121
884
5877
2342057
5216014
4954
kingdom
phylum
class
order
family
genus
species
Animalia
Chordata
Elasmobranchii
Rajiformes
4965
Rajidae
Amblyraja
Amblyraja radiata
1
44
121
884
5877
2420436
2420446
kingdom
phylum
class
order
family
genus
species
```

Where am I wrong?

P.S: this kind of `list` `l` is an output of packages `rgbif`, with code:

```
    keySpecies <- c(5216014,2420446)
    l.1 <- occ_search(taxonKey=keySpecies,
      limit=1, return='hier',
      curlopts=list(verbose=F))
l <- l.1[c(1:length(unique(keySpecies)))] #cut all element of list that are not useful
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lapply(l,function(x) x[7])` is close, but you need to index `[row, column]`, not just `[row]`. Instead do this:

```
res = lapply(l,function(x) x[7, c("name", "key")])
# or more simply
res = lapply(l, "[", 7, c("name", "key"))
```

This will still give you a `list`, which you'll need to combine together into a single data frame:

```
do.call(rbind, res)
```

---

Edit: I installed your package and ran your code, and apparently `l` is a list of lists of data frames, not a list of data frames. So we need to extract that as well:

```
res = lapply(lapply(l, "[[", 1), "[", 7, c("name", "key"))
res = do.call(rbind, res)
res
#                      name     key
# 5216014     Raja montagui 5216014
# 2420446 Amblyraja radiata 2420446
```

Comment: R tell me: Error in x[7, c("name", "key")] : incorrect number of dimensions